# Proxy pass remote_user with nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, proxypass

I have a firewall that is the SSL terminator and sets the remote_user header. This header should be passed onto an application, however we have an nginx proxy sitting in the middle.

Browser over SSL -> Firewall proxy -> Nginx proxy -> App

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pass the remote_user header to the App from the Firewall. Nginx seems to swallow it. $remote_user doesn't have it (which makes sense). $http_remote_user doesn't have it (which doesn't make sense). I tried to find it in $proxy_add_* but couldn't.

How do I proxy pass the remote_user header when the SSL terminator isn't nginx?

EDIT1: Other things I have tried:

```
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_pass_header remote_user;
proxy_set_header other_user $http_remote_user;

proxy_pass http://scooterlabs.com/echo;
```

Comment: proxy_set_header remote_user bob; works great though... for bob.

Comment: Are you sure that your firewall proxy is successfully setting the `remote_user` header? Does nginx even receive it?

Comment: It was set,  underscores_in_headers on; as gargsms stated below was the missing link.

Comment: @Thomas can you update the answer to include the header suggested by gargsms  and mention that it is updated.

Comment: @Nitb It already is in the answer and already does indicate it was updated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `proxy_pass_request_headers on` and `underscores_in_headers on` since your header contains an underscore.

`underscores_in_headers` needs to be placed in your http block.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers

**OLD ANSWER**

You are looking for `proxy_pass_header`

See: [Module ngx_http_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_header)

Comment: No effect (Example in post)

Comment: I could hug you.